How can I take the shippiment id with the OrderId in Amazon API?
how are you?
I need a help with the Amazon API. First, what I need is just get the order label in PDF or ZPL format.
I found the route https://developer-docs.amazon.com/amazon-shipping/docs/shipping-api-v2-reference that I can use the "shippingId" to get the label link, however I didn't find when can I get this shippingId.
I've analyzed the order API but according with the documentation, the "shippingId" isn't returned.
I don't pretend create the label, like the https://developer-docs.amazon.com/amazon-shipping/docs/tutorial-purchase-a-shipment-directly suggest, I just want download. Is it possible? Can anyone help me?
Now I'm just analyzing the documentations, I try to research about shippingId in the order API but I didn't found.
